# jQuery SlideDown and Border - Strange jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I use jQuery's SlideDown feature on an element that has a border, I do have a problem with a strange jump.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean:  http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/um9xj/
I've placed the duration on 700 just for testing purposes

```
$(element).slideDown({
    duration: 700
}).parent().addClass("active");
```

When you click the new items button you see the behaviour that I mean.
I hope that there is a very simple solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/um9xj/7/)**

It looks like as this is being animated down, the `margin-top` is applied and it jumps down a pixel.

*Edit* - the left border issue looks to be because you're positioning the `menucontents` element `left:-4px` which puts it outside of the `menu` element. This isn't an issue until you do the slideDown() animation and it automatically sets `menu` to `overflow:hidden` a simple fix is to move the positioning to the parent element.

CSS:

```
.icon .menu { 
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 #888; 
   display: none; 
   left:0px;
   top: 60px;
  /* margin-top:-1px; */
}

.menucontents {
  //other styles

 /* left: -4px */
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's almost correct, but it seems that there is still a bug with the left border. The left border only appears when the animation is complete. Any idea on how to solve that one?

Comment: Thanks again, but if I look at the fiddle now, the menu is not positioned correct anymore. I want the menu to be showed at the left and at the bottom just as it was, with your change -1px and 4px the position has changed, that's not the general idea. Sorry for that, but do you think you have another solution?

Comment: Add `left: 0;` to the first CSS class and your solution works.

Comment: Any chance of an updated demo? The provided link returns a 404. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery slideUp and slideDown animations animate the `height` of the content box, the `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top`, and `padding-bottom`. Your `margin-top: -1px` was getting animated but can only be 1 or 0, which is why it was jumping halfway through. Getting rid of `margin-top` will fix this. If you would like to avoid changing your CSS, you can override the margin editing like this:

```
$(element).slideDown({
    duration: 700,
    progress: function(){$(element).css('marginTop', '-1px')}
}).parent().addClass("active");
```

The progress function is called each frame of the animation and will overwrite jQuery's changes to your margin

EDIT: I've tried experimenting with overwriting overflow, but for reasons I can't determine, it isn't rendering properly. I recommend a CSS edit for your second problem. Since you want to position the menu, just use the outer-most div to modify your positioning and let the inner divs only worry about content:

```
.icon .menu {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #888;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.menucontents {
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    /* left: -4px; *
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, I feel i'm coming to a solution with your approach, unfortunately, the left border only shows when the animation is completed. Any idea on how to solve that one?